# Tomcat server configuration at \Servers\Tomcatv7.0 Server at localhost-config is missing

Tags: tomcat

I have an error while running a .jsp file in Eclipse IDE.When I try to run it says:Tomcat server configuration at \Servers\Tomcatv7.0 Server at localhost-config is missing.Check the server for errors.Please help.(By the way I'm using JDK7).

Answer (score 1):

I just updated my Tomcat admin port to 8005 then it worked.

[image: Change port screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your configuration is corrupted or incomplete

To re-configure tomcat in eclipse

1) Copy all files from TOMCAT_7_HOME/conf to WORKSPACE_FOLDER/Servers/Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config

2) Start Eclipse

3) In Package/Project Explorer go to Server -> Tomcat v7.0 Server

4) Click F5 to reload the server configuration

5) Start tomcat

[Here](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.stardust.docs.wst%2Fhtml%2Fwst-integration%2Fconfiguration.html) you can find detail steps to configure tomcat in eclipse

Answer (score -1):

Deleting the tomcat and re-creating it solved the issue